# Query an array element in an JSONB Object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb, lateral

I have a `jsonb` column called `data` in a table called `reports`. Here is what `report.id = 1`  looks like

```
[
    {
        "Product": [
            {
                "productIDs": [
                    "ABC1",
                    "ABC2"
                ],
                "groupID": "Food123"
            },
            {
                "productIDs": [
                    "EFG1"
                ],
                "groupID": "Electronic123"
            }
        ],
        "Package": [
            {
                "groupID": "Electronic123"
            }
        ],
        "type": "Produce"
    },
    {
        "Product": [
            {
                "productIDs": [
                    "ABC1",
                    "ABC2"
                ],
                "groupID": "Clothes123"
            }
        ],
        "Package": [
            {
                "groupID": "Food123"
            }
        ],
        "type": "Wearables"
    }

]
```

and here is what `report.id = 2` looks like:

```
[
    {
        "Product": [
            {
                "productIDs": [
                    "XYZ1",
                    "XYZ2"
                ],
                "groupID": "Food123"
            }
        ],
        "Package": [],
        "type": "Wearable"
    },
    {
        "Product": [
            {
                "productIDs": [
                    "ABC1",
                    "ABC2"
                ],
                "groupID": "Clothes123"
            }
        ],
        "Package": [
            {
                "groupID": "Food123"
            }
        ],
        "type": "Wearables"
    }
]
```

I am trying to get a list of all entries in `reports` table where at least one of `data` column's element has following:
`type` = `Produce` AND
where any elements of `Product` array OR any elements of `Product` array's `groupID` start with `Food`

So from the example above this query will only return the first index since

1. The type = `Produce`
2. groupID starts with `Food` for first element of `Product` array

The second index will be filtered out because type is not `Produce`.

I am not sure how to query to do AND query for `groupID`. Here is what I have tried to get all entries for type `Produce`

```
 select * from reports r, jsonb_to_recordset(r.data) as items(type text) where items.type like 'Produce';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample structure and result: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ef0b4ed86890e4045e05bbff0fed7431)

```sql
select r.*
from reports r
         cross join jsonb_array_elements(r.data) l1
         cross join jsonb_array_elements(l1.value -> 'Product') l2
where l1 ->> 'type' = 'Produce'
and l2.value ->> 'groupID' ~ '^Food';
```